# GPU optimization with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, windows-10, gpu

I am running Keras on a Windows 10 computer with a GPU. I have gone from Tensorflow 1 to Tensorflow 2 and I now feel that fitting is much slower and hope for your advice.

I am testing whether Tensorflow sees the GPU with the following statements:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

K._get_available_gpus()
```

giving the response

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 17171012743200670970
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 6682068255
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 5711519511292622685
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
```

So, that seems to indicate that the GPU is working?

I am training a modified version of ResNet50 with up to 10 images (257x257x2) as input. It has 4.3M trainable parameters. Training is very slow (could be several days). Part of the code is shown here:

```
import os,cv2,sys
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io
import h5py
import time
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers
from buildModelReduced_test import buildModelReduced
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

K.set_image_data_format('channels_last') #set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

# Check that gpu is running
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
K._get_available_gpus()

# Generator to read one batch at a time for large datasets
def imageLoaderLargeFiles(data_path, batch_size, nStars, nDatasets=0):
---
---
---          
yield(train_in,train_target 


# Repository for parameters
nStars = 10
img_rows = 257
img_cols = 257
bit_depth = 16
channels = 2
num_epochs = 1
batch_size = 8
data_path_train = 'E:/TomoA/large/train2'
data_path_validate = 'E:/TomoA/large/validate2'
nDatasets_train = 33000
nDatasets_validate = 8000
nBatches_train = nDatasets_train//(batch_size)
validation_steps = nDatasets_validate//(batch_size)
output_width = 35;   
runSize = 'large'
restartFile =  ‘’

#%% Train model

if restartFile == '':

    model = buildModelReduced(nStars,img_rows, img_cols, output_width,\
               batch_size=batch_size,channels=channels, use_l2_regularizer=True)
    model.summary()
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)

    all_mae = []

    adam=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None,
                         decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='MSE',metrics=['mae'])


history = model.fit_generator(imageLoaderLargeFiles(data_path_train,batch_size,nStars,nDatasets_train),
                    steps_per_epoch=nBatches_train,epochs=num_epochs, 
                    validation_data=imageLoaderLargeFiles(data_path_validate,batch_size,nStars,nDatasets_validate),
                    validation_steps=validation_steps,verbose=1,workers=0,
                    use_multiprocessing=False, shuffle=False)

print('\nSaving model...\n')
if runSize == 'large':
    model.save(runID + '_' + runSize + '.h5')
```

When I open Windows task manager and look at the GPU, I see that the memory allocation is 6.5GB, copying activity less than 1%, and CUDA about 4%. Disk activity is low, I read a cache of 1000 data sets at a time from an SSD. See screen clip below. I think that shows that the GPU is not working well. The CPU load is 19%. I use a batch size of 8, if I go higher, I get an resource exhausted error.

Any ideas on how to proceed or where to find more information? Any rules of thumb on how to tune your run to exploit the GPU well?

[image: Task manager screen]

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a bottleneck somewhere on a training operation that we can not detect by looking at Task Manager. It can be caused by I/O, GPU, or CPU. You should detect which part of the processing is slow with using an advanced tool.

You can use [TensorFlow Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler) to inspect all processes of the TensorFlow. Also, it gives suggestions that how you can speed up your processes. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXHAQIhhMhI) is a simple video tutorial about it.

[image: TensorFlow Profiler]